# How to to prevent EF from retrieving certain objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Excuse me for my broken English.

In my application, all objects in the context have a property called ObsoleteFlag, which basically means if the object should still be used on the frontend. It's some sort of "soft-delete" flag without actually having to delete the data.

Now I want to prevent EF from returning any object where ObsoleteFlag is set to true (1)

If for example I retrieve object X, the navigational list property Y contains all the related objects of type Y, no matter what the ObsoleteFlag is set to.

Is there some general way of preventing EF from doing this? I don't want to check on the ObsoleteFlag property everywhere I access the context, and for every navigational property that may be loaded too.

Thanks and sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help solve your problem. I just want to say: Don't worry about your English - it's better than a lot of what we see here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different approaches:

1. In your repository layer have a `GetAllWhatever()` that returns `IQueryable<Whatever>` and uses `Where(x => !x.Obsolete)` and use this whenever you retrieve objects of this type.
2. Create a view of `Create View ActiveWhatever As Select * from ActiveWhatever Where obsolete = 0` and bind to that rather than the table.

The first is essentially checking the flag every time, but doing so in one place, so you don't have to keep thinking about it.

The second is much the same, but the work is pushed to the database instead of the .NET code. If you are going to modify the entities or add new entities you will have to make it a modifiable view, but just how that is done depends on the database in question (e.g. you can do it with triggers in SQL Server, and triggers or rules in PostgreSQL).

The second can also include having a rule or trigger for `DELETE` that sets your obsolete property instead of deleting, so that a normal delete as far as Entity Framework is concerned becomes one of your soft-deletes as far as the database is concerned.

I'd go for that approach unless you had a reason to object to a view existing just to help the application's implementation (that is you're heavily into the database being "pure" in being concerned with the data rather than its use). But then, if it's handy for one application it's likely handy for more, given the very meaning of this "obsolete".

Comment: I like the idea of views. Thanks.

Comment: Views may be problematic if you need to perform updates against the view.  I would recommend creating Repository classes/methods that interact with Entity Framework and implement your business rules.  You might also have scenarios where you need to undo a Obsolete update so you will need full access to your database.

Comment: @MikeBurdick views can work quite nicely with updates if they're updatable views, as I discuss. In one recent project I was involved in we used views precisely to make updates easier, as it made it easy to have the EF-using project just use lat/long pairs for what in the database was using PostGIS objects, meaning that the EF didn't have to do the conversions at all which both made it simpler and guaranteed consistency with other applications using the PostGIS.